# Magento programmatically set the position of a watermark?

Tags: image

Sometimes the pre-defined watermark positions are not enough and we may need custom positions, such as 25% below the middle center, etc.

I found [this method](http://docs.magentocommerce.com/Mage_Catalog/Mage_Catalog_Helper_Image.html#setWatermarkPosition) but it seems protected.

Is there any way to programmatically set the position of a watermark? Such as by position of pixels from the top left of the image? For now I can set size and opacity of the watermark programmatically:

```
$this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image')
    ->constrainOnly(TRUE)
    ->keepAspectRatio(TRUE)
    ->keepFrame(FALSE)
    ->setWatermarkImageOpacity(6)
    ->setWatermarkSize(
        iGetWatermarkSize(600)
    )
    ->resize(600, null)
```

Wherein iGetWatermarkSize() is my in-house function that returns the size string for the watermark according to the width of the subject image.

I think it's sensible to have a method to set the position of a watermark in Magento but found nothing relevant in Google in this regard. Is there such a method or way for me to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an public function [Mage_Catalog_Helper_Image::watermark()](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Helper/Image.php#l308-l315)

**But you have to pass watermark image to this function as parameter.**

```
/**
 * Add watermark to image
 * size param in format 100x200
 *
 * @param string $fileName
 * @param string $position
 * @param string $size
 * @param int $imageOpacity
 * @return Mage_Catalog_Helper_Image
 */
public function watermark($fileName, $position, $size=null, $imageOpacity=null)
{
    $this->setWatermark($fileName)
        ->setWatermarkPosition($position)
        ->setWatermarkSize($size)
        ->setWatermarkImageOpacity($imageOpacity);
    return $this;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that looks like it! But how should I provide the $position? Is there any examples? Is it a pre-defined string like 'Bottom/Right' or pixel position values or?

Comment: Please check this https://chillydraji.wordpress.com/2015/02/26/to-add-new-positionin-watermark-magento/ .